# Error when running postgresql COPY Command

Tags: postgresql, copy, command, psql

Would like to be able to add characters like '-' in the schema name when running COPY command in postgresSQL. Any way to get around this ? Thanks!

```
`psql -d postgres -c "\COPY (SELECT * FROM test-schema.tableName) TO data.csv DELIMITER ',' CSV"

 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"`enter code here`
 LINE 1: COPY  ( SELECT * FROM test-schema.tableName ) TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',...`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes though I tend to discourage it.

[Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the standard.

> There is a second kind of identifier: the delimited identifier or quoted identifier. It is formed by enclosing an arbitrary sequence of characters in double-quotes (").

So:

```
create schema "test-schema";
CREATE SCHEMA

\dn "test-schema" 
    List of schemas
    Name     |  Owner   
-------------+----------
 test-schema | postgres

create table "test-schema"."test-table"(id int);

select * from test-schema."test-table";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: select * from test-schema."test-table";

select * from "test-schema"."test-table";
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

As you see, if you double quote an identifier to get around the identifier naming rules then you are bound to always quoting it.